# Creating a calculated field to show 'Red' 'Amber' or 'Green' based on a due date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, json-formatting, microsoft-lists

I am trying to create a calculated column to return "Red" "Amber" or "Green" based on a due date.

I have a date column called "Due Date" and I am trying to add a calculated column as follows: If the due date is greater than 7 days, will return "Green". If the due date is between now and 7 days then calculated column value will be "Amber" and if the due date is less than today, "Red".

Can someone please help me out with the formula - I have already inserted the below JSON for conditional formatting and this works but would like the calculated field to work in conjunction.

```
=if([$field_8]>(@now+604800000), 'Green', if[$field_8]> @now && [$field_8]<(@now+604800000), 'Amber', 'Red'))
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula for your calculated column like:

```
=IF([Due Date] > (TODAY() + 7), "Green", IF(AND([Due Date] >= TODAY(), [Due Date] < (TODAY() + 7)), "Amber", "Red"))
```

If `TODAY()` is not working for you, try replacing it with `NOW()`.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display* names of your columns in the formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))